# Does anyone know of an HTTP Server library that works on the Compact Framework?

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I am creating a remote test runner for Gallio.  My plan is to create an HTTP Web Service server.  I am comfortable creating the server myself, but I would prefer to use an existing HTTP server.  Does anyone know of an HTTP server that is appropriate for building a web service server.  It would be ideal if it is open source.

Pat O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably port [Cassini](http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx) to CF pretty easily.

Comment: I may take a look at this if I am not able to find a solution.  I did a quick compile and there would be a fair amount of work.  The System.Web.Hosting namespace does not exist for CF 2.0.  All the types used from that namespace would need to be written.  Still that is less work than starting from scratch :-).

Comment: As there does not seem to be any other open source alternatives I will go this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [RemObjects Internet Pack](http://www.remobjects.com) for .NET (and CF .NET). It's free and source code is included.

It contains a simple but working HTTP Server class. The webservices part you will have to code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If spending a lot of money is an option, checkout "Padarn" at http://www.opennetcf.com. It is supposed to give you a small footprint ASP.NET on your CE device.